# CoffeeScript split function not working as expected

Tags: arrays, split, coffeescript

I am trying to split a string into array elements by splitting on a comma, using CoffeeScript.

```
stringArray = string.split(',')
for element in stringArray
    console.log element
```

The problem I am having is that some of the components don't get console logged when iterating through the array. I expect an output of 9 substrings, as there are 8 commas.

Instead, 5 elements are output and 4 aren't. They aren't appended to other elements or anything like that, just missing.

Here is the string I am trying to parse, the bolded elements are the ones that are misbehaving:

> A|downstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|PMF1-BGLAP|ENSG00000260238|Transcript|ENST00000490491|protein_coding|||||||||||134|1||SNV|HGNC|HGNC:42953|||U3KQ54|UPI000046FD09||||,A|non_coding_transcript_exon_variant|MODIFIER|PAQR6|ENSG00000160781|Transcript|ENST00000491107|processed_transcript|7/7||ENST00000491107.5:n.1738C>T||1738|||||||-1||SNV|HGNC|HGNC:30132||||||||,A|non_coding_transcript_exon_variant|MODIFIER|PAQR6|ENSG00000160781|Transcript|ENST00000492619|processed_transcript|7/7||ENST00000492619.5:n.1978C>T||1978|||||||-1||SNV|HGNC|HGNC:30132||||||||,A|downstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|PMF1|ENSG00000160783|Transcript|ENST00000497069|nonsense_mediated_decay|||||||||||3748|1|cds_start_NF|SNV|HGNC|HGNC:9112|||V9GYH6|UPI0003B92863||||,**A|3_prime_UTR_variant|MODIFIER|PAQR6|ENSG00000160781|Transcript|ENST00000540423|protein_coding|5/5||ENST00000540423.5:c.*395C>T||1584|||||||-1||SNV|HGNC|HGNC:30132|||Q7Z4Q8|UPI00001B3F57||||**,A|downstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|PMF1-BGLAP|ENSG00000260238|Transcript|ENST00000567140|protein_coding|||||||||||252|1||SNV|HGNC|HGNC:42953|||A0A087WT04|UPI0001ED050B||||,**A|3_prime_UTR_variant|MODIFIER|PAQR6|ENSG00000160781|Transcript|ENST00000612424|protein_coding|6/6||ENST00000612424.4:c.*395C>T||1892|||||||-1||SNV|HGNC|HGNC:30132|||B4DJ42|UPI00017A70F0||||**,**A|3_prime_UTR_variant|MODIFIER|PAQR6|ENSG00000160781|Transcript|ENST00000613336|protein_coding|5/5||ENST00000613336.4:c.*395C>T||1454|||||||-1||SNV|HGNC|HGNC:30132|||Q7Z4Q8|UPI00001B3F57||||**,**A|3_prime_UTR_variant|MODIFIER|PAQR6|ENSG00000160781|Transcript|ENST00000623241|protein_coding|5/5||ENST00000623241.3:c.*395C>T||1816|||||||-1||SNV|HGNC|HGNC:30132|||Q7Z4Q8|UPI00001B3F57||||**

Any input is much appreciated!

**Solved**

Turns out it was a downstream issue. I had if statements that used 'return', thinking it would continue the iteration while it actually just terminated it. Replaced those 'return' statements with 'continue' and it worked. Thanks for all input, both about the question and about the format of the question!

Comment: I [tried it](https://jsfiddle.net/9q72xzeL/) and I get nine pieces.  Maybe some of the comma-looking characters in your source are not commas, but copying them into SO has turned them into commas.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Perl.  I removed that tag

Comment: This is not Perl, Javascript, and it's kind of like Python but not really… **what language is it?!**

Comment: Sorry, I included the Perl mention, and I'm not sure why

Comment: Well, it's still not Javascript. Is it some dialect? If so, mention that.

Comment: Whoops, I completely forgot this was coffee

Comment: Tag the user you wish to be notificatied of your comment, by ATusername, here @deceze I suppose. Consider James's comment

Comment: Haha thanks, this has been a good lesson in question posting and vetting for me. Thanks @zdim

Comment: Welcome.  Also, pay close attention to comments. You may get enough in a to-the-point half-sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works as is. Here is the compiled JS:

```js
var element, i, len, string, stringArray;

string = "A|downstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|PMF1-BGLAP|ENSG00000260238|Transcript|ENST00000490491|protein_coding|||||||||||134|1||SNV|HGNC|HGNC:42953|||U3KQ54|UPI000046FD09||||,A|non_coding_transcript_exon_variant|MODIFIER|PAQR6|ENSG00000160781|Transcript|ENST00000491107|processed_transcript|7/7||ENST00000491107.5:n.1738C>T||1738|||||||-1||SNV|HGNC|HGNC:30132||||||||,A|non_coding_transcript_exon_variant|MODIFIER|PAQR6|ENSG00000160781|Transcript|ENST00000492619|processed_transcript|7/7||ENST00000492619.5:n.1978C>T||1978|||||||-1||SNV|HGNC|HGNC:30132||||||||,A|downstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|PMF1|ENSG00000160783|Transcript|ENST00000497069|nonsense_mediated_decay|||||||||||3748|1|cds_start_NF|SNV|HGNC|HGNC:9112|||V9GYH6|UPI0003B92863||||,A|3_prime_UTR_variant|MODIFIER|PAQR6|ENSG00000160781|Transcript|ENST00000540423|protein_coding|5/5||ENST00000540423.5:c.*395C>T||1584|||||||-1||SNV|HGNC|HGNC:30132|||Q7Z4Q8|UPI00001B3F57||||,A|downstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|PMF1-BGLAP|ENSG00000260238|Transcript|ENST00000567140|protein_coding|||||||||||252|1||SNV|HGNC|HGNC:42953|||A0A087WT04|UPI0001ED050B||||,A|3_prime_UTR_variant|MODIFIER|PAQR6|ENSG00000160781|Transcript|ENST00000612424|protein_coding|6/6||ENST00000612424.4:c.*395C>T||1892|||||||-1||SNV|HGNC|HGNC:30132|||B4DJ42|UPI00017A70F0||||,A|3_prime_UTR_variant|MODIFIER|PAQR6|ENSG00000160781|Transcript|ENST00000613336|protein_coding|5/5||ENST00000613336.4:c.*395C>T||1454|||||||-1||SNV|HGNC|HGNC:30132|||Q7Z4Q8|UPI00001B3F57||||,A|3_prime_UTR_variant|MODIFIER|PAQR6|ENSG00000160781|Transcript|ENST00000623241|protein_coding|5/5||ENST00000623241.3:c.*395C>T||1816|||||||-1||SNV|HGNC|HGNC:30132|||Q7Z4Q8|UPI00001B3F57||||";

stringArray = string.split(',');

for (i = 0, len = stringArray.length; i < len; i++) {
  element = stringArray[i];
  console.log(element);
}
```

I just threw your code into [CoffeeScript.org's "Try It" feature](http://coffeescript.org/#try:string%20%3D%20%22A%7Cdownstream_gene_variant%7CMODIFIER%7CPMF1-BGLAP%7CENSG00000260238%7CTranscript%7CENST00000490491%7Cprotein_coding%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C134%7C1%7C%7CSNV%7CHGNC%7CHGNC%3A42953%7C%7C%7CU3KQ54%7CUPI000046FD09%7C%7C%7C%7C%2CA%7Cnon_coding_transcript_exon_variant%7CMODIFIER%7CPAQR6%7CENSG00000160781%7CTranscript%7CENST00000491107%7Cprocessed_transcript%7C7%2F7%7C%7CENST00000491107.5%3An.1738C%3ET%7C%7C1738%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C-1%7C%7CSNV%7CHGNC%7CHGNC%3A30132%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%2CA%7Cnon_coding_transcript_exon_variant%7CMODIFIER%7CPAQR6%7CENSG00000160781%7CTranscript%7CENST00000492619%7Cprocessed_transcript%7C7%2F7%7C%7CENST00000492619.5%3An.1978C%3ET%7C%7C1978%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C-1%7C%7CSNV%7CHGNC%7CHGNC%3A30132%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%2CA%7Cdownstream_gene_variant%7CMODIFIER%7CPMF1%7CENSG00000160783%7CTranscript%7CENST00000497069%7Cnonsense_mediated_decay%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C3748%7C1%7Ccds_start_NF%7CSNV%7CHGNC%7CHGNC%3A9112%7C%7C%7CV9GYH6%7CUPI0003B92863%7C%7C%7C%7C%2CA%7C3_prime_UTR_variant%7CMODIFIER%7CPAQR6%7CENSG00000160781%7CTranscript%7CENST00000540423%7Cprotein_coding%7C5%2F5%7C%7CENST00000540423.5%3Ac.*395C%3ET%7C%7C1584%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C-1%7C%7CSNV%7CHGNC%7CHGNC%3A30132%7C%7C%7CQ7Z4Q8%7CUPI00001B3F57%7C%7C%7C%7C%2CA%7Cdownstream_gene_variant%7CMODIFIER%7CPMF1-BGLAP%7CENSG00000260238%7CTranscript%7CENST00000567140%7Cprotein_coding%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C252%7C1%7C%7CSNV%7CHGNC%7CHGNC%3A42953%7C%7C%7CA0A087WT04%7CUPI0001ED050B%7C%7C%7C%7C%2CA%7C3_prime_UTR_variant%7CMODIFIER%7CPAQR6%7CENSG00000160781%7CTranscript%7CENST00000612424%7Cprotein_coding%7C6%2F6%7C%7CENST00000612424.4%3Ac.*395C%3ET%7C%7C1892%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C-1%7C%7CSNV%7CHGNC%7CHGNC%3A30132%7C%7C%7CB4DJ42%7CUPI00017A70F0%7C%7C%7C%7C%2CA%7C3_prime_UTR_variant%7CMODIFIER%7CPAQR6%7CENSG00000160781%7CTranscript%7CENST00000613336%7Cprotein_coding%7C5%2F5%7C%7CENST00000613336.4%3Ac.*395C%3ET%7C%7C1454%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C-1%7C%7CSNV%7CHGNC%7CHGNC%3A30132%7C%7C%7CQ7Z4Q8%7CUPI00001B3F57%7C%7C%7C%7C%2CA%7C3_prime_UTR_variant%7CMODIFIER%7CPAQR6%7CENSG00000160781%7CTranscript%7CENST00000623241%7Cprotein_coding%7C5%2F5%7C%7CENST00000623241.3%3Ac.*395C%3ET%7C%7C1816%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C-1%7C%7CSNV%7CHGNC%7CHGNC%3A30132%7C%7C%7CQ7Z4Q8%7CUPI00001B3F57%7C%7C%7C%7C%22%0AstringArray%20%3D%20string.split('%2C')%0Afor%20element%20in%20stringArray%0A%20%20%20%20console.log%20element).